# Regular Expression in Java for a set of integers

Tags: java, regex

Never tried this pattern matching in Java before and i'm trying to get it to match: Int<-Int*Int where * can be * or +. The matcher returns true to matching the pattern but when i try and use group() it returns an error saying no match. I've tried it with this code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)<-(\\d+)[\\*\\+](\\d+)$");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(instrLine);
            System.out.println(m.group());
```

I've tested it with 1<-2*3 and matching returns true i can just get it with group().
I'm assuming its something wrong with the regular expression.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: add `if (m.find())` before your last line

Comment: @syb0rg: why? `group()` denotes the whole pattern, not just the first group...